# Excel data entries of several persons and/or synchronization

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question about an Excel file where several people can save something at the same time. Maybe I will explain what I have and what I am trying to do.

I have an Excel file with UserForm1, UserForm1 opens directly when I open the file. Inside UserForm1 are automatically generated buttons (based on column A and B of workbook "Table1". I have a button and textboxes so that I can make new entries in columns A and B and generate new buttons.

So far everything is working. I have saved the file in our shared drive and tested whether 2 people can use it at the same time,

**Result:** Yes, both can open the UI (Excel file) at the same time - one read-only, of course.

**Problem:** Unfortunately, the person who has opened the file read-only cannot generate new entries. He can  but its not showing in columns A and B.

**Question:** Is there a possibility to work with a database or Sharepoint or similar instead of an excel workbook "Table1" but keep my UI, where several people can generate and save entries at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you can connect Excel to an Access database for example and keep your Userform UI.

Comment: @braX that means, i just need to collect data for my buttons from the access database instead of my workbook? can more the one people add entries and generate buttons even wenn second people opened the UI (excel file) as read only?

Comment: A read-only version of Excel will have no problems communicating read/write with the database, and multiple people can read/write the data at the same time. You can still run into problems if 2 users are trying to write to the same record tho.

Comment: huh okay, I'll try to connect a database insted of collum A and B..
yeah thats true.. but for this 2 people must entry data at the exact same time, right? but maybe I can also write a code, if database it realizes that 2 entries at same time comes, a msg button will pop up and say way 2 sec. before entry or sth...

Comment: Note that the Access file will have to be on a network drive that all the users have access to (not the internet) and they will need read/write access to that drive.

Comment: Thank you @braX, I connected now my UI to a Database, im getting my datas from there and add there new datas.. Now ill try it if more people can access and add new buttons / datas.